# The font for inactive UI elements in Eclipse look "doubled," or as if they have shadows

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, fonts

I'm not talking about the text editor font, rather parts of the Eclipse UI. I'm using Eclipse 2018-12 on Windows 7, with the DevStyle plugin. To illustrate what I mean, notice how the word "Location" has a shadow, and how the Browse button is difficult to read.

[image: notice how the word "Location" has a shadow, and how the Browse button is difficult to read.]

I've looked at the Eclipse help documentation, searched this site and others, and examined the Eclipse settings in "General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts," but I can't figure out what controls the appearance of those elements.

The one clue I have is that in the Colors and Fonts menu under "View and Editor Folders," some of the options such as "Inactive, selected color part begin" say in their descriptions that the setting is overridden by CSS. I'm guessing that comes from the DevStyle plugin themes.

Is there any way to change this particular setting? Am I looking in the wrong place in the Eclipse settings? Does Windows determine how inactive UI elements in Eclipse appear, or can this be changed from within Eclipse? Finally, where would one find the CSS responsible for overriding those settings (if that does in fact have something to do with this issue)?

Comment: I think you need to report each occurrence of this to the eclipse bugs list. They have fixed a few of these in the past couple releases but many more remain.

Comment: @emilles Please report bugs to Eclipse if and only if the issue can be reproduced in Eclipse without any additional third parties plug-ins like DevStyle (which is, as far as I know, closed source).

Comment: I'm fairly certain that DevStyle is causing this behavior, as I've never seen anything like that when using Eclipse in Ubuntu. Even if DevStyle is closed source, couldn't I modify those fonts with another CSS document and override the changes from DevStyle?

Answer (score 0):

According to this, it's a known issue with DevStyle. https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/with-darkestdark-devstyle-theme-greyed-out-text-looks-odd-and-hard-to-read/#post-609200

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in a recent DevStyle build. For more on this particular release, read this [blog post](https://www.genuitec.com/devstyle-adds-mojave-dark-more/).